# How to derive the formula for combinations?

Tags: combinations, proof-explanation

I was looking for derivations for formulas of permutations and combinations and I have found [this](http://www.zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/math/probability/counting.html) page. The page starts the derivation of combinations formula (the last section of the page) with the following:

> To derive a formula for C(n, k), separate the issue of the order in
>   which the items are chosen, from the issue of which items are chosen,
>   as follows.
>
> The number of permutations of k items taken from n items is
>
> ( number of sets
>   of k items taken from n ) × ( number of ways to order the k items ).

Yes, it is intuitive but how do we really know that this is indeed the case? In other words, can we rigorously show that

> The number of permutations of k items taken from n items is
>
> ( number of sets
>   of k items taken from n ) × ( number of ways to order the k items ).

?

Answer (score 1):

Note that what you have written in words is the expression: $\binom{n}{k} k!$.
(Since $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from a collection of $n$ objects, and $k!$ is the number of ways to order $k$ objects).
We could rewrite this as 
$$\binom{n}{k} k! = n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1).$$ Using induction on $k$, you can show that this is the right number.

Additional notes:

Their idea is pretty intuitive, but making their idea of "separating the issues" rigorous is much less straightforward than just noting that ordering a $k$ subset of $n$ objects is the same thing as just ordering them in the order that you pick them out. So there are $n$ choices of your first object, $n-1$ choices of your second object, and so on... We can make this rigorous using induction. Assume that the above formula holds for choosing $k-1$ objects. Then to choose $k$ objects, first choose $k-1$ objects. We know by induction that there are $n(n-1)\dots(n-k+2)$ ways of doing so. Now we must choose the last object. There are $n-(k-1) = n-k+1$ objects left. And so the number of ways of choosing the $k$ objects with an ordering is $n(n-1)\dots(n-k+2)(n-k+1)$. By induction the formula holds for all $k$.

So we can see that what they had is correct by rephrasing the problem into something that is easier to see inductively.

Comment: I don't know how should I use induction on k. Could you elaborate the answer?